# Windows Server 2012 Scheduled Task window title is taskeng.exe (but not always)

Tags: scheduled-task, command

We have several scheduled tasks running console apps on a Windows Server 2012 machine. When many of these run, and the console command window appears, the window title is "taskeng.exe" but sometimes it shows the path of the job it is running (i.e. "C:\path\program.exe").

Any idea what causes it to show the actual job sometimes and other times not? I would like to make all of the windows show the job name it is running, if that is a setting that can made, instead of just the generic taskeng.exe name.